# Dereferencing pointer to entire array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm learning pointers to (entire) arrays in C.

Suppose I declare a 2d matrix of ints:

```
int arr[3][3] = 
    {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9}
    };
```

Now, I declare a pointer of appropriate type:

```
int (*ptr)[3][3];
```

Initialize it:

```
ptr = &arr;
```

Now, ptr contains the address of arr.

```
  ptr --->&(arr[0][0]   arr[0][1]   arr[0][2]
            arr[1][0]   arr[1][1]   arr[1][2]
            arr[2][0]   arr[2][1]   arr[2][2])
```

So, when we dereference ptr, it should yield the first location, isn't it?

`printf("%d", *ptr)` gives an error at compile time. To print the first element, I've to use `***ptr`.

I have 2 questions:

1. I can't understand the need for a triple dereferencing.
2. If `*ptr` doesn't point to first element of array, what does it point
   to?

Comment: Why would you expect `*&arr` to refer to `arr[0][0]` instead of `arr`? That's like expecting `*&some_int` to refer to the int's first byte, rather than the entire int.

Comment: I am confused because int is a primitive type whereas array is a collection of primitives. Printing the array will require looping over all it's elements, unlike an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf(*ptr);
```

is wrong since the first argument to `printf` needs to be a string that specifies the format to use to print the rest of the arguments. To print the address, use:

```
printf("%p", *ptr);
```

> I can't understand the need for a triple dereferencing.

The type of `p` is `int (*)[3][3]`.

The type of `*p` is `int [3][3]`.

The type of `**p` is `int [3]`

The type of `***p` is `int`.

When you have a pointer like that, it's best to use the array syntax.

```
(*p)[0][0]
```

The generic form would be:

```
(*p)[i][j]
```

That is a lot less confusing than using `***p`. Besides, `***p` can be used to access the `[0][0]-th` element of the array only.

> If `*ptr` doesn't point to first element of array, what does it point to?

Hopefully the answer to the previous question explains this.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Got it.

Comment: `%p` expects `void*`. So you trigger UB. It should be `printf("%p", (void*)*ptr);`

Comment: @tstanisl, Any object pointer can be used where `void*` is expected. I don't understand why leaving out the explicit cast  would cause UB.

Comment: @RSahu, because C standard does not  require pointer types to have the same binary representation as `void*`. Serializing pointer of type `int*` and deserializing it as `void*` is not defined by the standard. Thus one must do a cast to be portable