# Unable to de-reference rows using pointer to entire array

Tags: c, pointers

I have declared an array and a pointer to entire array as given in the below code. (Note: I have done this just to understand the concept and I am not intending to use this method. Instead I will be using array of pointer method)

```
    int ar1[3][3]={
                    {11,12,13},
                    {21,22,23},
                    {31,32,33},
                    };
    int (*intPtrToAr1)[] = &ar1[0];
    int rowCnt;
    int colCnt;
    for(rowCnt=0;rowCnt<3;rowCnt++)
    {
        for(colCnt=0;colCnt<3;colCnt++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",*(*(intPtrToAr1)+colCnt));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

I am able to de-reference the elements of first row correctly. As expected above code prints the first row 3 times. But I am unable to de-reference the subsequent rows. I tried using something like

```
printf("%d\t",*(*(intPtrToAr1+rowCnt)+colCnt));
```

But I get error message invalid use of array with unspecified bounds. I understand there is some issue. My understanding is that intPtrToAr1 points to entire array and hence intPtrToAr1+rowCnt will point to subsequent rows. But could not find the exact reason to the problem. I referred [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326628/dereferencing-pointer-to-entire-array). But I guess this is slightly different than that post. I am using Code::Blocks and mingw.

Comment: when writing code, you always want to write the simplest code that performs the desired operation.   The posted code seems to be trying to obfuscate the code.  That is never a good idea.  (amongst other reasons, in 6months or 6years someone will have to maintain that code.  If the code is not straight forward, and there is no reason for the obfuscation the maintainer will cuss out the original writer/coder, then throw that piece of code away and re-write it in a straight forward manner.

Comment: @user3629249: I fully Agree with you. Such code may not be maintainable. That is why I have clearly written in my post that this code is not for implementing. It is only for understanding the concept. I am just a beginner and going through C now. Just thought of asking this issue to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I get error message invalid use of array with unspecified bounds.

Adding `rowCnt` gives an error because the compiler simply doesn't know where your row lies. To let the compiler know that, you need to give your pointer array your ***column size*** for compiler to know after how many memory locations to *hop* to the next row. (The compiler needs to know this because memory is allocated in a contiguous fashion i.e straight line).

```
int (*intPtrToAr1)[3] = &ar1[0];
```

Then to dereference the rows, simply add rowCnt to the print statement like this:

```
printf("%d\t",*(*(intPtrToAr1+rowCnt)+colCnt));
```

Output:

```
$ gcc test.c && ./a.out
11      12      13
21      22      23
31      32      33
```

Comment: I guess dynamic mmory allocation can be done as 'intPtrToAr1=malloc(3*3*sizeof(int));'

Comment: Is this method of allocating or manipulating multidimensional array is common?  I guess array of pointers (or double pointers) or using single pointer (with offset of row*col+row) is commonly used. May be a personal choice. Or any specific application?